# SQL Get first date/time when a value went above AND stayed above another value

Tags: sql-server

My tables hold values and setpoints. I want to run a stored procedure during a breached setpoint to get the first date/time when the value breached. 
The SP I have obviously just brings back the first time it breached during the times specified in the query but I want it for the current breach.

Realistically I want to do away with the DateAndTime parameters as a breach could last multiple days.

```
SELECT TOP (1) DateAndTime
FROM Temps INNER JOIN Temps_Setpoints ON Temps.ProbeID = Temps_Setpoints.ProbeID
WHERE (Temps.ProbeID = @ProbeID) AND (Temps.Temp >= Temps_Setpoints.Hi)
AND DateAndTime BETWEEN '10/31/2017 00:00:00' AND '10/31/2017 23:59:59'
ORDER BY DateAndTime
```

[Hopefully my image will explain better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEQXI.png)
[image]

I am thinking that it is not possible in a SP and may have to bring back a set of date and loop through it in code.

Any suggestions?

[Picture to explain further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrmQr.png)

Comment: You don't need to loop here but I am not really sure what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: don't you want the most recent (`MAX`) time the setpoint is breached instead of the first?

Comment: @Beth Not necessarily.  It's possible that the setpoint is crossed because the value is *decreasing*.  It's very possible to have a data set with an intersection of the setpoint, but no valid result of this query.

Comment: Max results in the latest date and time which on my graph would be at the "now" point not the point where the current breach started

Comment: Can you please add a short script with test data (read: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) on how to do that easily).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, this was a rush, I'll ensure I include scripts and more detail next time. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having sample data I can use on my own machine (I don't need the typing practice), this is untested:

```
;With CTE as (
SELECT
   DateAndTime,
   Temps.Temp,
   Temp_Setpoints.Hi
FROM Temps INNER JOIN Temps_Setpoints ON Temps.ProbeID = Temps_Setpoints.ProbeID
WHERE (Temps.ProbeID = @ProbeID)
)
SELECT MIN(DateAndTime) as DateAndTime
FROM CTE
WHERE DateAndTime > (select MAX(DateAndTime) from CTE where Temp < Hi)
```

I've done it as a CTE so that you can add more columns, extend the logic, etc.

Basically, I negated your premise - rather than trying to find a "became true and remained true", I try to locate the last time that the predicate was *false* and then select the earliest row that comes after that.

(I'm also using aggregates rather than `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` since I believe it more clearly expresses the *intent* of the query)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.DateAndTime
FROM Temps t
INNER JOIN Temps_Setpoints ts
    ON t.ProbeID = ts.ProbeID
WHERE (t.ProbeID = @ProbeID) AND (t.Temp >= ts.Hi)
    AND t.DateAndTime >= '10/31/2017 00:00:00' 
    AND t.DateAndTime <  '11/01/2017 00:00:00'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Temps ex
        WHERE ex.ProbeID = t.ProbeID
            AND ex.DateAndTime > t.DateAndTime
            AND ex.DateAndTime <  '11/01/2017 00:00:00'
            AND ex.Temp < ts.Hi
    )
ORDER BY t.DateAndTime
```

I added table aliases and qualified all columns to make it a bit more clear which tables are being referred to.

The NOT EXISTS subquery looks for readings from the same probe that were recorded afterwards (but before the end of the range) that had a temp below the setpoint's high.

I also removed the BETWEEN expression because you may have fractional seconds (e.g., `10/31/2017 23:59:59.253` is a valid `datetime`).  `MyDateTime >= '10/31/2017 00:00' AND MyDateTime < '11/01/2017 00:00:00'` is generally a better pattern even though BETWEEN seems more convenient.

Comment: I tried this but it still brings back the last date time (being "now") not the entry where the current breach occurred. I have added another image to clarify.